# Can't authenticate to MLFlow

Tags: python, authentication, mlflow

I can't authenticate to MLFlow using the Python client.

This returns `200`:

```py
import requests
response = requests.get(
    "http://myhost:5000/",
    auth=(USER, PASSWORD),
)
```

This returns `401`:

```py
os.environ["MLFLOW_TRACKING_USERNAME"] = USER
os.environ["MLFLOW_TRACKING_PASSWORD"] = PASSWORD
mlflow.set_tracking_uri("http://myhost:5000/")
existing_experiment = mlflow.get_experiment_by_name(experiment_name)
```